# Using a generator resulting in insufficient memory error

Tags: python, generator, keras

I have the following generator in python. It takes in samples which is an array which consists of x rows where each row looks something like this

```
['some\\path\\center.jpg', 'some\\path\\left.jpg', 'some\\path\\right.jpg', 'someNumber']

def generator(samples, batch_size):
num_samples = len(samples)
while 1: # Loop forever so the generator never terminates
    shuffle(samples)
    for offset in range(0, num_samples, batch_size):
        batch_samples = samples[offset:offset+batch_size]

        for batch_sample in batch_samples:

            source_path = np.random.choice([batch_sample[0], batch_sample[1], batch_sample[2]])
            filename = source_path.split(os.sep)[-1]
            current_path = 'data20/IMG/' + filename
            current_image = cv2.imread(current_path)
            current_angle = float(batch_sample[3])

            if source_path == line[1]:
                current_angle += 0.2

            elif source_path == line[2]:
                current_angle -= 0.2

            images.append(current_image)
            angles.append(current_angle)

        # trim image to only see section with road
        X_train = np.array(images)
        y_train = np.array(angles)
        yield (X_train, y_train)
```

Then I have some CNN where I train the network with the generator with the given function

```
model.fit_generator(train_generator, samples_per_epoch=len(train_samples), validation_data=validation_generator, nb_val_samples=len(validation_samples), nb_epoch=5)
```

**My Question:** How come the time rises during training, so that it takes longer and longer.. leading to insufficient memory for a batch size of lets say 32??

Comment: You do not clear image and angle? So they keep getting bigger and bigger

Comment: Thanks for the tip, that totally fixed it. All I had to do was to initialize image and angle inside the generator in front of the for "batch_sample in batch_samples:"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Dref360 mentioned, I do not clear image and angle inside my generator. The main Problem was that i put

```
images = []
angles = []
```

outside of my generator, which resulted in both growing each cycle, where they should have been inside my generator. Below is the working code:

```
['some\\path\\center.jpg', 'some\\path\\left.jpg', 'some\\path\\right.jpg', 'someNumber']

def generator(samples, batch_size):
num_samples = len(samples)
while 1: # Loop forever so the generator never terminates
    shuffle(samples)
    for offset in range(0, num_samples, batch_size):
        batch_samples = samples[offset:offset+batch_size]

        images = []
        angles = []
        for batch_sample in batch_samples:

            source_path = np.random.choice([batch_sample[0], batch_sample[1], batch_sample[2]])
            filename = source_path.split(os.sep)[-1]
            current_path = 'data20/IMG/' + filename
            current_image = cv2.imread(current_path)
            current_angle = float(batch_sample[3])

            if source_path == line[1]:
                current_angle += 0.2

            elif source_path == line[2]:
                current_angle -= 0.2

            images.append(current_image)
            angles.append(current_angle)

        # trim image to only see section with road
        X_train = np.array(images)
        y_train = np.array(angles)
        yield (X_train, y_train)
```

**Big thanks** to **Dref360** :D